# BottomSheetDialogFragment with a passed in Lambda crashes when app backgrounded

Tags: android, kotlin, lambda

I have a button sheet dialog which takes a lambda as param and will execute the lambda when user click on the button on dialog. Everything works great but I realized that when I background the app, it crashes the app, and here is the stacktrace.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Parcelable encountered IOException writing serializable object (name = com.XXX.$PASS_IN_METHOD$1)
        at android.os.Parcel.writeSerializable(Parcel.java:2125)
        at com.xxx.xxx.writeToParcel(Unknown Source:43)
```

The lambda in this case is a network call which will be invoked when user click on the button on dialog, and dismiss the dialog upon finishing the task.

I had put

```
@Parcelize
    class MyBottomSheetDialog(
        val task: (() -> Completable)
    ) : Parcelable
```

but it seems complaint about the `task` isn't serializable. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Lambdas can never be parceled, so this pattern is never safe. Is there a reason you aren't using the APis for [returning a result from a fragment](https://developer.android.com/guide/fragments/communicate#fragment-result)?

Comment: @ianhanniballake can you elaborate how the link will help achieve the same goal? In my case here, the dialog can take an operation and operates the task when button click. ( dialogs takes task passed from caller) vs the link seems to be having fragment B does a fixed set of operation and pass back to fragment A, with no flexibility